# Where does IE9/Vista store cookies?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I'm testing my website on my local computer and I can't find the cookie in the Temp Internet Files folder. But there is definitely a cookie somewhere, because when I close browser and open again, I'm still logged on at my website. I'm using vista by the way.

Comment: Why can't you clear cookies the normal way though the internet settings page?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: I need to monitor the cookie content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View cookies in Internet Explorer by viewing the Temporary Internet Files. Open your IE browser. Click "Tools" then select "Internet Options." Click "Settings" under Browsing History. Click "View Files" to view Temporary Internet Files. Further if you want to look into the Folders checkout **[THIS](http://www.milincorporated.com/a2_cookies.html)**

Comment: Hi I have found it in the "Low" folder as described in the article.

Comment: @Aperture: this answer is [incomplete](http://superuser.com/a/726565/33589).

Answer (score 1):

To delete all cookies click on the gear in the top right corner and go to internet options.

On the general tab, under browsing history, click `delete...`.

In the new window you can check the box to delete all of your cookies.

---

If you want the "Temp Internet Files folder" by default it is

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
```

but you can move it. You can find the current folder  by clicking settings in the browsing history section from the first part of this answer and click `View Files`. You can delete cookies individually from that folder if you wish.

Comment: There's [another folder in which Windows hides cookies](http://superuser.com/a/726565/33589).

Answer (score 0):

The answers by Vima and Scott are incomplete. I've deleted cookies the official way, and was surprised to see that Gmail still remembered as what user I was last logged in. That was because you must remember to *un*check the deceivingly-looking "Preserve Favorites website data" button in the Delete Browser History dialog:

[image]

To completely wipe out IE9 cookies, do this:

1. Wipe out `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies` and its `Low` subfolder
2. Wipe out `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files`

If by some odd chance a site still seems to have access to cookies, press F12 for the developer tools, then from the Cache menu, select "Clear cookies for domain". For your curiosity, you can choose "View cookie information", to see where they were, then wipe out that directory too.